Adjusting A Script That Deletes Duplicates On Other Sheets
I was given this script that deletes all duplicates from Sheets 1, 2 & 3 as they come into Sheet4. I need to adjust it so it does not delete duplicates if, when the Job Number comes into ColA Sheet4, it reassigns it from MO123456 to MO123456^1 in Col B. Anything over or equal to ^2 should be treated a a duplicate that needs deleted from Sheets 1, 2 & 3.
In other words when it assigns it ^1 that is actually an original job number and any job numbers >= ^2 is a job number that has been submitted more then once.
In lines 46-52, I tried grabbing the incremental number from the second field of the array defined by split (^) and then adding a test to see if the incremental number was greater then 1. However this did not work. What changes do I need to make?
function onEdit(e) {
  const sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  const range = e.range;


  if (sheet.getName() === "Sheet4" && range.getColumn() === 1) {
    const jobNumber = range.getValue();

    if (jobNumber) {

      const versionedJobNumber = generateJobNumber(jobNumber);
      sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), 2).setValue(versionedJobNumber);

      removeMatchingRows(jobNumber);
    }
  }
}

function generateJobNumber(jobNumber) {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet4");
  const data = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();
  let version = 0;

  data.forEach((row) => {
    const existingJobNumber = row[0];
    if (existingJobNumber && existingJobNumber.split("^")[0] === jobNumber) {
      version++;
    }
  });

  return `${jobNumber}^${version}`;
}

function removeMatchingRows(jobNumber) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheetsToCheck = ["Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3"];

  sheetsToCheck.forEach(sheetName => {
    const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
    if (!sheet) return;

    const data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    const rowsToDelete = [];


    data.forEach((row, index) => {
      const baseJobNumber = row[0].split("^")[0];
      const baseJobNumberVer = row[0].split("^")[1];
      if (baseJobNumber === jobNumber && baseJobNumberVer > 1) {
        rowsToDelete.push(index + 1);
      }
    });

    rowsToDelete.reverse().forEach(rowIndex => {
      sheet.deleteRow(rowIndex);
    });
  });
}


Keep in mind that simple trigger functions must complete within thirty seconds. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions

Converts the value to integer
The main issue with your existing code, is that you are extracting the value as a string (which is typically happens when using split() method), not as a number which causes an issue while processing inside the condition.  You need to convert it to an integer to match your condition.
Modified code:
function removeMatchingRows(jobNumber) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheetsToCheck = ["Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3"];

  sheetsToCheck.forEach(sheetName => {
    const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
    if (!sheet) return;

    const data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
    const rowsToDelete = [];

    data.forEach((row, index) => {
      const baseJobNumber = row[0].split("^")[0];  
      const baseJobNumberVer = +row[0].split("^")[1]; //this converts the value to integer before the condition

      if (baseJobNumber === jobNumber && baseJobNumberVer > 1) {  
        rowsToDelete.push(index + 1);
      }
    });

    rowsToDelete.reverse().forEach(rowIndex => {
      sheet.deleteRow(rowIndex);
    });
  });
}

If you want to check what type of value your code returns use the following code, this helps you debug your code more effectively.
console.log(typeof baseJobNumberVer);  

References:

Split()
Unary +

